# Entropy change of system,surrounding and universe

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy

So if a system goes from state A to state B then change in its entropy ,if the process is reversible,is integral of dQ/T. And if it is irreversible then the change in entropy is larger than this integral.Correct?However referring to the book Concepts in thermal physics (page 138,example 14.1)they have given that a small system is placed in contact with a thermal reservoir. This process is irreversible. But changes in entropy are calculated as if it is a reversible process. Is the book wrong or have I not understood something?

Answer (score 0):

Process being irreversible does not imply anything definite about validity of the formula $dS = \frac{dQ}{T}$. It may be valid, it may not.

For example, if the process is such that there is no entropy production inside the system, and temperature of the system $T$ remains constant throughout the system but is lower than temperature of the reservoir $T_r$ it takes heat from, then

$$
dS = \frac{dQ}{T} 
$$
is valid. Also, the Clausius inequality implies

$$
dS > \frac{dQ}{T_r}.
$$

Both of these are valid at the same time, because $T<T_r$.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be referring to the book Blundell & Blundell: Concepts in thermal physics. To understand what is done there you must note that all processes in the reservoir is reversible, it can be a sink or source for arbitrary amount of thermal energy and entropy always exchanged at the same temperature, $T_R$, and always reversibly.

The small sample at $T$ has heat capacity $C$. "Smallness" just means that internally is uniform and has no measurable effect on the reservoir's ability to maintain its own temperature. Ignoring all mechanical, ie., pressure-volume interactions, etc., if the samples' temperature is increased by contact to $T+dT$, then it has absorbed $CdT$ thermal energy, "heat", AND along with that it has also absorbed $\frac{CdT}{T}$ entropy, since the energy exchange occurred at $T$.
You can integrate both entropies but nothing here so far is irreversible. Irreversibility comes from somewhere else and its presence is the reason for the two integrals are not being the same. It is there because because $T_R$ is constant while the sample temperature, $T$, changes. Either $T_S \le T <T_R$ or $T_R <T \le T_S$, the entropy exchanged is via *conduction* that itself is inherently irreversible and produces entropy.

*Heat conduction* is always irreversible and produces between two infinitesimally close temperatures $\delta S(x) = -\frac{S(x)}{T(x)}\delta T$ entropy, that is, if at the higher temperature $T(x)$ end of a conductor enters entropy $S(x)$, then at the lower temperature end $T(x)+\delta T$ the entropy that leaves the conductor at location $x+\delta x$ is $S(x)+\delta S$. Important to note that this is the way a conductor conserves *thermal energy* $T(x)\delta S +S(x) \delta T = \delta (T(x)S(x))=0$

Answer (score 0):

No, your relationship for an irreversible process in not correct.  For an irreversible process, $$\Delta S\gt\int{\frac{dQ}{T_B}}$$where $T_B$ iii the temperature at the interface (boundary) with the surroundings.

To get the change in entropy for a closed system experiencing an irreversible process, you must devise an alternate reversible process between the same initial and final states, and evaluate the integral of dQ/T for that alternate process.  In the example you cited, the reversible path will not just involve a single reservoir at constant temperature T.  It will involve as sequence of reservoirs at temperatures running from the initial temperature of the body to its final temperature.